# How to store an array of nested objects using Sails.js with MongoDB?

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to save an nested object inside a sails.js model.
This is how it looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
      label: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true,
      },
      consumption: [{
        timestamp: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true,
        },
        value: {
          type: 'float',
          required: true,
        },
      }],
  }
};
```

To include the values inside the array I'm doing the following (inside the controller):

```
if(!plug.consumption)
    plug.consumption = [];

plug.consumption.push({
    timestamp: req.param('timestamp'), /* Format: '2016-04-14T16:18:24.972Z' */
    value: req.param('value'), /* Format: '6.5' */
});

plug.save(function (err){
    if(err){
        res.send("Error");
        return next(err);
    }
});
```

But when the plug.save is executed, sails breaks and says `Error: Unknown rule: 0`

I've searched how to store arrays of objects on sails.js but didn't find anything that would work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your syntax used in `consumption` attribute of your model is supported by Waterline. it looks like a separate model having a One-to-Many relationship.

Comment: Humm...are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax used in `consumption` is wrong or at least not documented. Waterline supports attribute types `json` and `array` [as documented](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/data-types-attributes.md) but you can't define a schema for them. To define a schema you have to use a [One-to-Many relationship](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/associations/one-to-many.md) between your model and a consumption model.